Filter just the id number from a URL in BeautifulSoup
I've gotten to a point where
print(soup.td.a)

results in
<a href="/?p=section&amp;a=details&amp;id=37627">Some Text Here</a>

I'm trying to figure out how I can filter further so all that results is
37627

I've tried a number of things including urlparse and re.compile but I'm just not getting the syntax correct.  Plus I feel like there is probably an easier way that I'm just not finding.  I appreciate any help given.

If you have a working query for the link, you now only need to parse its query string and extract id.

You can use the parse_qs() method to parse queries:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

html_content = '''
<td>
    <a href="/?p=section&amp;a=details&amp;id=37627">Some Text Here</a>
</td>
'''

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

# Find the <a> tag
a_tag = soup.find('a')

# Extract the href attribute
href = a_tag.get('href')

# Parse the URL to get the query parameters
parsed_url = urlparse(href)
# for py2: parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)

# Get the 'id' parameter
id_value = query_params.get('id', [None])[0]

print(id_value)  # Output: 37627



This worked for me but I needed to change
# Find the <a> tag
a_tag = soup.find('a')

to
# Find the <a> tag
a_tag = soup.td.a


There are two way to make this. You can simply cut the string from 'id=' to the next occurence of double quote character or '&' if it is possible that the link can have more query params or just use the regex. I would prefer to use the regex, as it is more simple and accurate.
FIRST SOLUTION:(Cut the string)
# check that the string contains the part 'id='
id_start = (soup.td.a).find('id=')
if id_start != -1:
    # id_start contains the index of 'id=', to get the actual index of the id we need to add 3 to this value
    id_start += len('id=')
    # we find the occurence of '"' starting from 'id=' index, if not found search for '&'
    id_end = (soup.td.a).find('"', id_start)
    if(id_end == -1):
         id_end = (soup.td.a).find('&', id_start)
    id_value = (soup.td.a)[id_start:id_end]

SECOND SOLUTION:
import re
# We create our regex to find the occurence of id in the string, this works by finid the id= string followed by one or more digits and getting this group of digits, .group(1) will return the group of digits
regex= r'id=(\d+)'
# .search finds the first occurence of the regex
match = re.search(regex, soup.td.a)
#if everything was fine it will find your id
if match:
    id_value = match.group(1)

Hope it works!!

Using a regular expression to parse a query string (while better than searching a query string for substrings) is not the best approach. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420259/parsing-query-string-using-regular-expression-in-python

Mmm, thanks for the link, can be useful even to the person that asked the question, but I still don't believe that making a parse and find the id is better than search with a regex. Can you explain me more about pls?
